# Setting tab focus on drop menu to make it keyboard accessible using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

The following jquery is intended to open a hover menu on tab focus, but is not setting the focus correctly.

Html

```
    <ul class="nav @if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice){@Html.Raw("nav-pills")}else{@Html.Raw("nav-pills")}">
            <li class="dropdown subTabAction" style="cursor:pointer" id="accessFunction">
   <a  style="color: lightgray; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #111; webkit-text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #111;font-size:18px;background-color:transparent;padding-right:5px" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >
```

jquery:

```
$("#accessFunction").focus(function () {
$("#accessFunction").toggleClass("hovered");
```

});

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Provide a complete working example

Comment: @Dekel  I do not currently have one, as the issue  is that this drop menu can receive focus, but does not hover on tab into

Comment: If you are looking for help you should take the time to provide all the information. In your case - is build a demo the show what exactly the problem is.

Comment: @Dekel I will build a jsfiddle now, and see if I can express the problem more correctly.